# Find string match in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have data.frame with 2 columns and thousands rows of random strings as:

```
Column1                      Column2
"this is done in 1 hour"     "in 1 hour"
```

I would like to get a new data.frame column like this:

```
Column3
"this is done"
```

So basically match the string according to the Column2 and get the remaining of Column1. How to approach this?

EDIT:

This would not solve the issues since the length of strings varies so I can't do:

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}

substrRight(x, 3)
```

So I would need something like `grepl` matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regular expression:

```
data <- data.frame(Column1 = "this is done in 1 hour", Column2 = "in 1 hour")
data$Column3 <- gsub(data$Column2, '', data$Column1) # Replace fist parameter by second in third.
```

EDIT: 
For more than 1 row, you can use `mapply`:

```
data <- data.frame(Column1 = c("this is done in 1 hour", "this is a test"), Column2 = c("in 1 hour", "a test"))
data$Column3 <- mapply(gsub, data$Column2, '', data$Column1)
```

Comment: I was thinking approaching it same way too, but I don't know why, I thought it is more complicated. Thanks.

Comment: This does not work in the expected way if the `data.frame` has more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
# example data frame
testdata <- data.frame(colA=c("this is","a test"),colB=c("is","a"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# adding the new column
newcol <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(testdata)),function(x) gsub(testdata[x,"colB"],"",testdata[x,"colA"],fixed=TRUE))
new.testdata <- transform(testdata,colC=newcol)

# result
new.testdata
#      colA | colB  | colC
# --------------------------
# 1 this is |   is  | th 
# 2  a test |    a  |   test
```

EDIT: `gsub(str1,'',str2,fixed=TRUE)` deletes all occurrences of `str1` within `str2` whereas using `sub` would only delete the first occurrence. Since `str1` is usually interpreted as regular expression, it is important to set `fixed=TRUE`. Otherwise a mess happens if `str1` contains characters such as `.\+?*{}[]`. To address the comment, the following would replace only the last occurrence of `str1` in `str2` leading to the desired output:

```
revColA <- lapply(testdata[["colA"]],function(x) paste0(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1)))
revColA <- lapply(revColA,paste,collapse='')
revColB <- lapply(testdata[["colB"]],function(x) paste0(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1)))
revColB <- lapply(revColB,paste,collapse='')

revNewCol <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(testdata)),function(x) sub(revColB[x],"",revColA[x],fixed=TRUE))
newcol <- lapply(revNewCol,function(x) paste0(substring(x,nchar(x):1,nchar(x):1)))
newcol <- sapply(newcol,paste,collapse='')

new.testdata <- transform(testdata,colC=newcol)

### output ###
#        colA   colB   colC
------------------------
# 1  |this is |   is | this 
# 2  | a test |   a  |   test
```

Comment: The colC, should have been `this`. Anyway, pretty close. Thanks.